# Why docker cli gives "No such file or directory" while that file shows up in `ls`

Tags: docker, go, bazel

I'm using bazel to run a go test, and in that `docker_test.go` file I'm using [docker go sdk's `ContainerCreate` function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client@v20.10.6+incompatible#ContainerAPIClient.ContainerCreate) to mount the local dir to docker. In the `BUILD.bazel` file, I'm writing

```
go_test(
    name = "docker_test",
    size = "enormous",
    srcs = ["docker_test.go"],
    embed = [":docker"],
    data = glob([
            "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/**",
    ]),
    deps = [
        "//pkg/util/contextutil",
        "//pkg/util/log",
        "@com_github_docker_docker//client",
        "@org_golang_x_net//context",
    ],
)
```

With `"docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/**",` exactly the folder that I'll mount to my docker container.

And I use bazel to run this go test, and the container is successfully started. I used `docker exec -it ... /bin/sh` to enter the cli, and in that cli it gave the following confusing results:

```
sh-4.4# cd docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
sh-4.4# ls
foo.txt  hello.sql  yes.sql
sh-4.4# cat ./hello.sql
cat: ./hello.sql: No such file or directory

sh-4.4# ls -al
ls: cannot access 'foo.txt': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'hello.sql': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'yes.sql': No such file or directory
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  160 Nov 28 22:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 28 22:57 ..
l????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? foo.txt
l????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? hello.sql
l????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? yes.sql
sh-4.4#
```

So it turns out that the folder I wanted seems successfully mounted to the docker container, but when I tried to look at the files inside, it somehow gave me "No such file or directory". But these files are actually there in the `ls`'s output! I'm so confused about this.

Comment: Is `hello.sql` a symbolic link? If it is so, and if the file it points to does not exist, it will give that error. Use `ls -l` to see.

Comment: ls -al should be a better option in case hello.sql acts different from a file or from a folder

Comment: @BurakSerdar and @sigur thanks for the suggestion! Added the output of `ls -al` to the question descp.